# MariaDB - my.cnf isn't in my server CentOs

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, my.cnf

I have been working with MariaDB and i don't know why there is no `my.cnf`. But the crazy thing is that:

1. Where it is suposed that the file should be, there is only the `my.cnf.d`, but the .cnf isn't.
2. If i write a new file called my.cnf and i copy from another server, it works.

I want to know why happen this?

PD: This is my instalation via `yum`:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
sudo systemctl start mariadb
mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the specific version there may be no my.cnf file. See [MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/)

MariaDB will use compiled defaults if there is no my.cnf to override them. You can use my.cnf.d as a starting point for that.